# Java Getting Last Item from JList

Tags: java, swing, client, chat, server

I am currently working on a java chat client, I already have the server and client working together. I am able to send messages between users and display them on a `JList`. What I'm having trouble with is when the user changes the font color and font style instead of changing the font properties for just that message it changes the style for the whole chat. Could there be anyway of getting the last item that was addded to the `JList` and changing its properties? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The short answer is, each line in the JList would need to carry rendering information (Font and Color) which your ListCellRenderer would need to use to make decisions about how a given line would need to be rendered. Just understand, this is expensive, as the JList will need to render every line to know how wide and long the JList needs to be in order to render itself...

Comment: @MadProgrammer in order to do it that way wouldn't I need to know the exact length that the List would be? Since this is a chat client I would not know what the length of the conversation would be.

Comment: Why?  Each "chat" entry would have it's own format information

Comment: Not that there's anything wrong with what you want to do, but isn't a text component better suited for chat than a `JList`? Is it some kind of log you want to keep?